# Blender 2.74 Depth-of-field is okay at 3D-viewport, but not in Render

Tags: 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine, depth-of-field

Blender 2.74 has enabled one to add a depth-of-field effect in the 3D viewport. The problem is, when I hit F12 to render the camera-view, the depth-of-field doesn't show up. Any idea why?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to achieve the in-render DOF through the compositor. Run your combined image through the Defocus node as well as your Z pass output. The output will be the image with DOF as it was in the viewport render.

[image]

Comment: How come it works like that?? I'm going to assume it doesn't behave like this in Cycles. I've had decent results in Cycles without this odd feature.

Comment: Yes, Cycles has in-camera DOF built in, BI does not currently.